# How to execute linux commands on a remote ubuntu server using symfony4?

Tags: linux, symfony, remote-server, ubuntu-18.04

I want to execute some linux commands like `docker run nginx` on a remote Ubuntu server. Let's say host A using my client interface on another host B developed in symfony4 and then the server (host A) will send some info after executing the command to the client interface on host B to be displayed on it.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Read about [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell), you probably want to run some `ssh` command programmatically. Asking for tools or software is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be fairly easy to run such commands using `exec`, but that is in no way related to Symfony itself

Answer (score -1):

at first you need to log in:

1. `ssh username@ip_address_of_server_with_symfony4`

Then

2. `cd /path/to/symfony4`

Then

3. `docker exec symfony_container_php php bin/console command:name --arguments`

If you need to run single command from your local computer, you also can use ssh -t

4. `ssh -t user@ip full;command;separated with;-es`